# Trying to add code that extract only lines that contains "word" and write a new .txt file from requests

Tags: python

This code opens a text file (`list.txt`) with websites and then extract URLS from webarchive.org from those websites, and write them to a new text file (`urls.txt`). I need to extract from web.archive.org only links that contain "word", but I am getting error:

```
if `word' in url:  IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Can someone explain why and give the right code here?

The code:

```
urls = []
with open("list.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        urls.append(line)

archive_url = "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey"

with open("url.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:

        r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
         if 'word' in url:
        print(r.text, file=f_out)
        print("\n", file=f_out)
```

Comment: In your code, the `if 'word' in url:` has an extra leading space character which is considered indentation, so it needs to be removed. The line after the `if` will need to have (4) leading spaces added to it otherwise you get another error.

Comment: i have made the correction, no errors appears, but nothing is writen to txt file

Comment: Then the conditional expression `'word' in url` was never `True` — and if nothing else the file should have contained one for more blank lines since that is done unconditionally. That should be easy enough to verify. I suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You have a leading space before the `if` statement
2. In the line after this statement, you must indent the code

This should solve your problem:

```py
urls = []
with open("list.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        urls.append(line)

archive_url = "http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=*.{}&output=text&fl=original&collapse=urlkey"

with open("url.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in urls:

        r = requests.get(archive_url.format(url))
        if 'word' in url:
            print(r.text, file=f_out)
            print("\n", file=f_out)
```

Comment: No errors appear, but nothing is writen to txt file :(

Comment: and if i replace "for url in urls" with "for url in archive_url", it does write to txt, but it skips the "if 'word' in url" and it writes all lines

Comment: Instead of using print statements, write to the txt file using `f_out.write(r.text)`. Also, check that `r.text` actually has something to write. It may be empty, which could cause nothing to be written to the file.